# NSAttributedString background colour for UITextField with Secure option

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I want to have red background for login/password fields when user specifies them incorrectly.

```
NSAttributedString *loginString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:_loginField.text attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}];
```

This code works great for login, but for `UITextField` with `Secure` option (password) it does not work at all.
Does iOS have any standard way to make background red under text field's stars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked just fine for me. I created 2 `UITextField`s, 1 regular and 1 secure, along with a button to take their contents and make their backgrounds attributed red exactly as you have written above:

```
NSAttributedString *loginString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:usernameField.text attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}];
[usernameField setAttributedText:loginString];

// field set as secure in xib
NSAttributedString *pwString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:passwordField.text attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}];
[passwordField setAttributedText:pwString];
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, is it work for iOS 6 too or only for iOS 7? I don't have iOS 6 simulator installed anymore(

Comment: Nor do I, so I have only tested on iOS 7 simulator.